# Need a zip locator feature on a site. Where to start?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have been tasked to create a site which has a dentist locator based on the zip code inputted.  There will be 8 dentists that will be available.  I will probably set up a table in a mysql database to hold the information on the dentists (more will be added in the future).

I just don't really know how to get started. I know it cant be all to hard to implement because soo many sites have it. Is there any free open source ways of doing this?  If I need to pay for some sort of zip database, so be it.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

I should add:  I will be using php/mysql/jquery.  The local is USA.

Comment: Once you've the data, it's relatively trivial to do great circle distances to get nearest, etc. It's the getting the data that can be challenging, depending on the locale you had in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the database you need, zip codes with lat/long co-ordinates
http://sourceforge.net/projects/zips/files/

and here is how you would implement  "find the zip codes within x miles of given zip code" (believe it is written in VB)

http://www.wwwcoder.com/Default.aspx?tabid=68&site=3551&parentid=451&type=art

Python Implementation:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/393241/

Math background:
http://www.meridianworlddata.com/Distance-Calculation.asp

Once you get this result set, you would match the doctors who are in these zip codes

Best of luck!!

Edit: My suggestion is you use your DB to return you the list of zip codes within "x" miles of a given zip code rather than doing it in PHP. Extending this, you can have a stored proc/function which can return a list of doctors within x miles of a given zip code. You might also want to handle pagination accordingly (if you are using pagination) (Limit & offset ,I guess in MySQL. might be wrong, its a long time since I used it)

Comment: thats a great start, though I am building the site using PHP, as I am much more familiar with it.